# Как перенаправить вывод функции printf?

Tags: c, boot

Выполняется код загрузчика операционной системы. Имеется только один процесс.
Как перенаправить вывод какой-либо сторонней функции на данном участке кода в буфер char* (функция печатает в stdout с помощью printf, код этой функции я исправить не могу)?

Команда, которая работает в консоли "> buffer", естественно, тут работать не будет, да и файлов никаких нет... Код написан на чистом C, но могу написать костыль и на C++.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему? Единственный способ, который я знал, тут не будет работать.

Comment: Кроме как посмотреть код используемой libio и если там для вывода в поток в структурах `FILE` применяются "виртуальные функции", то подменять их адреса на свои ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: как вариант, в головной закрываем stdout, затем открываем свой файл. У него будет дескриптор 2. И читать из него

Comment: Загрузчики же используют printk?

Comment: @JK_Action в данном случае используется другая функция

Comment: а нету функции типо freopen() ?

Comment: @pavel К сожалению, нет

Comment: Уточните: код не линкуется, или падает при исполнении?

Comment: @user58697 код работает. Стоит задача скрыть вывод функций в консоль, не меняя их исходного кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант решения через функцию `freopen()`, однако следует быть осторожнее в его использовании.

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];
freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout);
setbuf(stdout, buffer);             // весь вывод через printf будет в буфер
printf("simple print");
freopen("/dev/tty", "a", stdout);   // возвращаем печать в stdout на консоль
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

в Windows аналогом для `/dev/null` и `/dev/tty` служат `NULL` и `CONOUT$` соответственно.